# CoreNLP API for N-grams?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, n-gram, pos-tagger

Does CoreNLP have an API for getting unigrams, bigrams, trigrams, etc.?

For example, I have a string `"I have the best car "`.  I would love to get:

```
I
I have
the
the best
car
```

based on the string I am passing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are coding in Java, check out getNgrams* functions in the StringUtils class in CoreNLP.

You can also use CollectionUtils.getNgrams (which is what StringUtils class uses too)

Comment: I tried to use the getNgrams*  within the stanford pipeline, but what is becoming difficult is to pipe it back to the List<CoreLabel> from Collection<String>. I end up having an error `java.lang.String cannot be cast to edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel` How did u guys overcome the problem?

Comment: checkout CollectionUtils.getNgrams.

Comment: And how do you use this ngrams to train a custom NER model i mean, with CRFClassifier?

Answer (score 2):

You can use CoreNLP to tokenize, but for grabbing n-grams, do it natively in whatever language you're working in. If, say, you're piping this into Python, you can use list slicing and some list comprehensions to split them up:

```
>>> tokens
['I', 'have', 'the', 'best', 'car']
>>> unigrams = [tokens[i:i+1] for i,w in enumerate(tokens) if i+1 <= len(tokens)]
>>> bigrams = [tokens[i:i+2] for i,w in enumerate(tokens) if i+2 <= len(tokens)]
>>> trigrams = [tokens[i:i+3] for i,w in enumerate(tokens) if i+3 <= len(tokens)]
>>> unigrams
[['I'], ['have'], ['the'], ['best'], ['car']]
>>> bigrams
[['I', 'have'], ['have', 'the'], ['the', 'best'], ['best', 'car']]
>>> trigrams
[['I', 'have', 'the'], ['have', 'the', 'best'], ['the', 'best', 'car']]
```

CoreNLP is great for doing NLP heavy lifting, like dependencies, coref, POS tagging, etc. It seems like overkill if you just want to tokenize though, like bringing a fire truck to a water gun fight. Using something like [TreeTagger](http://www.cis.uni-muenchen.de/~schmid/tools/TreeTagger/) might equally fulfill your needs for tokenization.